# why is my liquid simulation baked like this?

Tags: fluid-simulation, mantaflow

[image]

The liquid simulation looks like particles in the right image how do i make it look like the image on the left

Answer (score 2):

You need to activate this single thing in your fluid domain:
[image]

[image]

[image]

This will give all those particles mesh around them, you need then adjust your settings to fit in your scene